# Can I somehow get the scrollViewDidScroll: UIScrollView Delegate method from UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I have an array of `UIViewController's` that I want to be able to scroll up and down between.  I have started with UICollectionView, but that doesn't provide the rotation that I want.  I tried using UIPageViewController, but it doesn't use view reuse and I can't adjust the transition using the x or y offset.

I have a workaround in mind for the view reuse, but I would also need to get the "scrollViewDidScroll:" calls from the `UIScrollView` that the `UIPageViewController` is using.  I didn't find anything useful in the `UIPageViewController` delegate.

Does anyone know of a workaround for getting the current scroll position or offset of a `UIPageViewController`?

Comment: From my experimentations (before abandoning a project using a `UIPageViewController`), the scrollView a `UIPageViewController` uses is private. What I did myself was to build my own `UIScrollView` controller myself.

Answer (score 0):

I grabbed a reference to it via...

1) The following snippet

```
for (UIView *view in savedStashesPageViewController.view.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        self.pageScrollView = (UIScrollView *)view;
        self.pageScrollView.delegate = self;
    }
```

2) Setting the UIScrollViewDelegate as appropriate

3) The following snippet

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

NSLog(@"%f",scrollView.contentOffset.x);

}
```